# count number of mails of a particular date in Outlook using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

Im writing a tool to move outlook mails to Excel, In it I have used two date picker, one  starting date and another to end date. I dont know how to form a loop that loops for a particular date and then jumps to next one.

```
for (DateTime j = fd; j <= td; j=j.AddDays(1))
{

                    var outlookXcell = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem) myInbox.Items[fd]);
                    MessageBox.Show(outlookXcell.SenderName);
                    var mailSub = outlookXcell.Subject;

                    var mailcontent = outlookXcell.Body;

                    var senderemailid = outlookXcell.SenderEmailAddress;
}
```

Comment: Please show what u have tried.

Comment: The "looping through dates" seems correct, so obviously the problem is somewhere else. The title of the question and the body don't really match. Please specify.

Comment: var outlookXcell = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem) myInbox.Items[fd]);

Above code is wrong and if it takes a date, it donot loop every mail in that date, My main focus is to filter mail by date and save them in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast doing R&D, I figured to solve. If u feel to help to optimize the code work better. Add comments.

```
int mCount = myInbox.Items.Count;
     for (int a = 1; a < mCount; a++)

            {
               var itemn = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[a];

                if (itemn.CreationTime >= fd && itemn.CreationTime < td)
                {
                    string subject = itemn.Subject;
                    DateTime reciv = itemn.CreationTime;
                    var mContent = itemn.Body;
                    var senderId = itemn.SenderEmailAddress;

                    worksheet.Cells[xlrow, 2] = reciv;
                    worksheet.Cells[xlrow, 3] = senderId;
                    worksheet.Cells[xlrow, 4] = subject + worksheet.Cells.WrapText;
                    worksheet.Cells[xlrow, 5] = mContent + worksheet.Cells.WrapText;
                    worksheet.Cells.WrapText = true;
                    xlrow++;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Do not do that. This is extremely inefficient. Use Item.Find/FindNext/Restrict.

Answer (score 1):

As Eugene mentioned, Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict will do the job. The query you need is something like the following: `([ReceivedTime] > '10/01/2014') AND ([ReceivedTime] < '12/01/2014'`)

Comment: Yes, In it first I filter it by date then I have to loop to the number of mails in it, So Im struggling to count number of mail of a particular date

Comment: If you call Restrict, all you have to do is read the Items.Count property from the collection returned by Restrict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods to get a collection of items that corresponds to your needs. For example, see [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/) .